# Typescript Angular2 Routing

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing

Hello I am totally new to Angular2 and Typescript,

I want to have two Links like this:
Admin
Calculation.

So when I Click on Admin Page, Admin page must be appear on that same page and
Calculation Page when click on Calculation.
I want to achieve this through Angular2 Routing and written in Typescript.
I already have Admin component and calculation component in My Angular2 App

Comment: Kindly go to the link https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-5/ts/eplnkr.html. You will get clear idea as well as the code to do Angular2 Routing using Typescripts.